# Pandas selecting a subset of rows before a certain value occurs in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to extract a subset of rows from my data frame before a value occurs in column Y, groupby column X.

For example, in this case, for each unique value in X, I want to extract all the rows before '1' occurs in Y, and the output should include the row where the first '1' encountered.

```
          X      Y      Z
 index 
 0        A      0     56
 1        A      0     67
 2        A      1     66
 3        A      0     83
 4        A      1     88
 5        B      0     52
 6        B      1     66
 7        B      1     70
 8        C      0     68
 9        C      0     72
 10       D      1     65
```

And my desired output is:

```
          X      Y      Z
 index 
 0        A      0     56
 1        A      0     67
 2        A      1     66
 5        B      0     52
 6        B      1     66
 8        C      0     68
 9        C      0     72
 10       D      1     65
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `apply` with the `cumsum()`x2 trick:

```
df[df.groupby('X').Y.apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().cumsum()).le(1)]

       X  Y   Z
index          
0      A  0  56
1      A  0  67
2      A  1  66
5      B  0  52
6      B  1  66
8      C  0  68
9      C  0  72
10     D  1  65
```

Answer (score 1):

Think in the different way `idxmax`

```
df[df.index<=df.groupby('X').Y.transform('idxmax')]
Out[110]: 
       X  Y   Z
index          
0      A  0  56
1      A  0  67
2      A  1  66
5      B  0  52
6      B  1  66
8      C  0  68
10     D  1  65
```

Comment: Nice one! Works well when the index is numeric.

Comment: @coldspeed yep , just about to mention that , also need unique index,